# AIX: how to change a password as root without setting the ADMCHG flag?

Tags: password, aix

I'd like to change the password of another user, as root, but don't want the user to be prompted to change their password when the log in.  As far as I can tell, any mechanism to change the password as root set the `ADMCHG` flag in `/etc/security/passwd`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
man pwdadm
pwdadm -c
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Use `passwd` to change the user's password: `passwd $user`
2. Use `pwdadm` command to cancel the password-change prompt: `pwdadm -c $user`

That's it! :)

Answer (score 2):

echo "user:n3w_p466w0rd" | /bin/chpasswd -c

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do it in an automated way?  If it's a one-off then change it to a temp password, then login as that user and change it to the desired password.